# SSIS connect to Azure Blob Storage 403 forbidden error

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

I am using SSIS 2019 and installing the Azure feature pack trying to connect Azure Blob Storage and download files on-premise. When executing the task it errors. Installed [TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16#use-tls-12) version.

To use TLS 1.2, add a REG_DWORD value named SchUseStrongCrypto with data 1 under the following two registry keys.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

Add new values named SystemDefaultTlsVersions with DWORD value=1

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

***Error Message:*** [Azure Blob Download Task] Error: Download task has stopped with exception: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

[image]

[image]

And still run into 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic may be blocked at the storage account.  Take a look at the networking blade for the storage account to see if your IP is being blocked.

[image: Storage account networking blade]

Comment: I did test out using Azure Storage Explorer connecting to Azure Blob Storage with my credentials and I am able to upload and download files.

Comment: May be relevant:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1465458/connect-to-adls-gen-2-from-ssis-2019